# Create Array in handlebarjs template and loop over it

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js

I've got two views. One is for creating an element (in this case a dropdown). The other is a formular where I want to place in the dropdown form. So the dropdown view is called directly from formular template.
I want to pass a array of options like this

```
{{> dropdown title='city' required='true' options=['Munich', 'New York'}}
```

On the other file I want to create all elements

```
{{#each options}}
  <li class="c-dropdown__item" data-dropdown-value="{{this}}">{{this}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

Any ideas how to create an array in template? My suggestions is that options is not a valid array.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to define the array in your template rather than in the data object that is passed to the template?

Comment: Yea I want to create different components for html object e.g. select field. These are called and defined inside the template.